# Split arrays from object and use in underscore template

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

Below is the response I get from the server using $.getJSON. I want to be able to call each array separately so I can use an underscore js template to output the data.

How can I split the arrays out or call each array separately to perform the necessary loop to show both the kept and passed data?

```
{
    kept: [
        0: {
            counter: "1",
            image: "image1.png",
            name: "alias"
        },
        1: {
            counter: "1",
            image: "image2.png",
            name: "lorem"
        }
    ],
    passed: [
        0: {
            counter: "1",
            image: "image3.png",
            name: ""dolores""
        },
        1: {
            counter: "1"
            image: "image4.png"
            name: ""quisquam""
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get **kept** and **passed** in template because these are object properties, like this

```
  <script type="text/template" id="tpl">
    <h1>kept</h1>  
    <% _.each(data.kept, function(el) { %>
      <p><%= el.name %></p>
      <p><%= el.image %></p>
      <p><%= el.name %></p>
    <% }); %>

    <h1>passed</h1>  
    <% _.each(data.passed, function(el) { %>
      <p><%= el.counter %></p>
      <p><%= el.image %></p>
      <p><%= el.name %></p>
    <% }); %>
  </script>

_.template($('#tpl').html(), {data: data})
```

[`Example`](http://jsbin.com/wefuqo/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign the server response to a variable `text` then do the following:

```
var text=$.getJSON ;
/* var text='{
kept: [
    0: {
        counter: "1",
        image: "image1.png",
        name: "alias"
    },
    1: {
        counter: "1",
        image: "image2.png",
        name: "lorem"
    }
],
passed: [
    0: {
        counter: "1",
        image: "image3.png",
        name: ""dolores""
    },
    1: {
        counter: "1"
        image: "image4.png"
        name: ""quisquam""
    }
]
}'; */

var json = JSON.parse(text);
var kept=json.kept;
var passed=json.passed;
/* then do what you want or loop through them with kept.length and passed.length*/
```

That should do it.